# Setting a date to embedded system using shell script

Tags: shell

i'm using embedded linux here i need to set the current date to system which is based on user input given by the key board,here i'm failing at one condition that is the system has to wait for 2 minutes un till gets input from keyboard if it reaches to specified wait time it has to come out from loop.......

Below is my piece of code:

```
echo please enter the date in below format 
echo YEAR- MM-DD HRS:MNS:SEC  and press enter 

read -e a1 
startd=$(date -s "$a1"); 

echo "$startd"; 

hwclock --systohc 
date
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use option `-t` in your the `read` command:

```
if read -e -t 120 a1; then
   echo "input: $a1"
else 
   echo "no input"
fi
```

From the bash man page:

> read [-ers] [-a aname] [-d delim] [-i text] [-n nchars] [-N nchars] [-p prompt] **[-t timeout]** [-u fd] [name ...]
>
> ...
>
> -t timeout
>      Cause  read  to  time out and return failure if a complete line of input (or a specified number of characters) is not read within timeout seconds.

Comment: Hello Oliv,  Thanks for your reply,........but it is not coming out of loop what i mean to say is after 120 seconds i'm unable to see the else part echo.

Comment: @Naveen.R There is no loop in the statement I posted. Do you mean the `read` command is blocking indefinitely? If so, please try with small values like `-t 1`.

Comment: @olive.....Thanks for your response,problem solved i removed the -e in if condition i tried like this way.... if read  -t 120 a1;..........now it is working fine which i expected.